# Kustos bag_unpack does not unpack my json dictionary string

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer, azure-monitoring

I have the following data, which i want to split into several columns in Kusto to get access to the values of the dictionaries entries:

[image]

This is the code i use to get the table from the picture:

```
let latestVersionAndroid = toscalar(customEvents
| where client_OS contains "Android"
| summarize max(application_Version));
let releaseDateLatestAndroid = toscalar(customEvents
| where client_OS contains "Android" and application_Version contains latestVersionAndroid
| summarize min(timestamp));
customEvents
| where timestamp > releaseDateLatestAndroid
    and name == 'Login'
    and client_OS contains 'Android'
    and application_Version == latestVersionAndroid
| project properties = customDimensions.Properties, application_Version
| evaluate bag_unpack(properties)
```

I thought that the last line would unfold the contents of properties and create a new table from it.
but as you can see in the image, it is simply displaying the same result as without the evaluate line.
is it because there are blanks in the keys that would be used as columnnames?
But i would except kusto to throw an exception, if it could not complete the operation because of this?
Is there another way to extract the data in Kusto to get access to the values of the keys?

Many thanks in advance,
Maverick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might happen because the "properties" that looks like json is actually a string. If this is the case you should try to parse the json as if it was string and then do the bag_unpack. For example change this line:

```
| project properties = customDimensions.Properties, application_Version
```

To this:

```
| project properties = parse_json(tostring(customDimensions.Properties)), application_Version
```

In order to access the colums with a whitespace you need to put them into square brackets like this

```
| summarize count()
    by application_Version, ["DW version"]
```

Comment: You are my hero of the day, sir. :)
Sometimes its the small things that you overlook. Many thanks for giving me the simple solution to this.

Comment: btw, i added a solution to access the colums with whitespace in them, so that other users will also benefit from this.